# Simple Form Rails configuration class for input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How do we add class for input in Simpleform configurations wrapper?

I tried below but it doesn't seem to be working

```
config.wrappers :horizontal, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-lg-8' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, my_wrapper_html: { class: 'form-control' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline text-danger' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Pls specify few things: what you mean that it doesn't work? Do you use any CSS framework and what is the version? What is written in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is to implement bootstrap 3?

try this

```
config.wrappers :horizontal, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error', defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } }  do |b|
b.use :html5
b.use :min_max
b.use :maxlength
b.use :placeholder
b.optional :pattern
b.optional :readonly

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
    input.use :label, class: 'horizontal'
    input.wrapper tag: 'div' do |prepend|
     prepend.use :input, class: 'horizontal'
    end
    input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
  end
end
```

taken from [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/857#issuecomment-23535620)

I also had to add [THIS](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/issues/26#issuecomment-22435894) to the config file too for inputs to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure it is possible to add any classes to input inside a wrapper. As far as I'm concerned this DSL of `b.use :input` has no such options.

You can use `input_html` option instead:

```
= f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'my-input-class' }
```

This feature described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage).

For most complex cases you can define your own input class under `app/inputs` directory:

```
class MyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  html_options = label_html_options.dup
  html_options[:class] ||= []
  html_options[:class].push('my-input-class')
  @builder.label(label_target, html_options) {
    build_check_box_without_hidden_field + template.tag(:span).html_safe
  }
end
```

Than use this input:

```
= f.input :title, as: :my_input
```